# How do convergence of $\lim_{x \to +\infty} |f(x)/g(x)| $ and being less than infinity of that imply and mean that $f(x)$ is upper-bounded by $g(x)$?

Tags: calculus, algorithms, asymptotics, computational-complexity

I'm trying to learn about asymptotic notation and I have some questions about some paragraphs that I've read.

> the Big O. And it's written like this. $f(x) = O(g(x))$.
> And it means that
> the $\lim_{x \to +\infty} |f(x)/g(x)| $ is convergence-- is less than infinity ( $\lim_{x \to +\infty} |f(x)/g(x)| < \infty$ ).
> So it's finite, and it
> can't diverge.
>
> The interpretation is that $f(x)$ function is up to constant factors
> upper-bounded by $g(x)$, that $f(x)$ grows the same rate or slower
> than $g(x)$ grows as $x$ gets large.

I have 2 questions from this paragraph.

1. How do convergence of  $\lim_{x \to +\infty} |f(x)/g(x)| $ and being less than infinity of that imply and mean that $f(x)$ is upper-bounded by $g(x)$? where does this interpretation come from? I'm trying to somehow imagine their curves but I cant and I have not any clue.
2. in "$f(x)$ function is *up to constant factors* upper-bounded by $g(x)$", what does ***up to constant factors*** mean? I'm not native English speaker and I'm not sure which meanings of "up to" is suitable for this situation and context.

Thanks.

Comment: 1. So we assume that $\left| {f(x)/g(x)} \right|$ converges as $x\to +\infty$. Let the limit be $C\geq 0$. Then by the definition of the limit at infinity, there is a $K>0$ such that for all $x>K$, $\left| {f(x)/g(x)} \right| \le C + 1$, i.e., $\left| {f(x)} \right| \le (C + 1)|g(x)|$. 2. It means that there is an $M>0$ so that $\left| {f(x)} \right| \le M |g(x)|$ for large $x$. It is bounded by $g(x)$ only up to a constant factor because $M$ is not necessarily $1$.

Comment: 1. why instead of $| \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} - C | $ < $\varepsilon$ , you wrote $|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}|≤C+1 $ ?  why we do not have $\varepsilon$ in your expression?            

     
     2. so the teacher have used ***"up to constant factors"***, only to emphasize that it's not bounded just by a single $g(x)$  and this $g(x)$ can have some constant. am I right?

Comment: @Mehdi the definition of limits holds for any positive number; it doesn't matter what you call it $\epsilon$ or not. $1$ is a positive number. So, for the number $1>0$, there is a $K_1>0$ such that for all $x>K_1$, we have $\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-C\right|<1$; hence by the triangle inequality, $\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|<C+1$. If you wanted, you could also say that $10$ is a positive number, so there is a $K_{10}>0$ such that for all $x>K_{10}$, we have $\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-C\right|<10$. This is just a matter of understanding what the phrase "for all $\epsilon>0$ (blablabla)" means.

Comment: @Mehdi 1. See the detailed explanation by peek-a-boo. 2. Yes, it is to emphasise that it may not be true that $|f(x)|\leq |g(x)|$ for all large $x$, but if you multiply the right-hand side by a suitable *fixed* positive constant $M$, it becomes true. You can say in English that $f$ is bounded by $g$ *up to a constant factor*. The thing is that since $M$ does not depend on $x$, the upper bound is similar in character to $g$ itself, i.e., $M\cdot g$ behaves similarly to $g$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank You So much.

Comment: @Gary Thank You VERY VERY MUCH Gary. No one had ever explained it to me so clearly and beautifully, but you did. and the last question. according to the inequality you wrote in your first answer (which is very similar to the famous classic definition of Big-Oh and I think they are not just same as each other but they are both equal to each other), I've came to the conclusion that, in fact, you reached to the definition of Big-oh through the formal definition of limit at infinity. am I right?